# How to define a path for Firestore document that includes a specific key?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I am trying to use Firestore's new extension to delete all user data.

Their example documentation says the following:

> Which paths in your Cloud Firestore instance contain user data? Leave
> empty if you don’t use Cloud Firestore. Enter the full paths,
> separated by commas. You can represent the User ID of the deleted user
> with {UID}. For example, if you have the collections users and admins,
> and each collection has documents with User ID as document IDs, then
> you can enter users/{UID},admins/{UID}.

However, the real data I need to delete are in other Collections whereby a foreign key equivalent is the user ID.  I want to remove those values, for example, from the learnTransactions Collection that have UserID = the specific {UID}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ["Delete User Data" extension](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/delete-user-data) it is not possible to delete documents based on a the value of one of their fields.

As you will see in the [source](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/7e235af87aa8327c55677fabdefe5d6bc3e7acc5/delete-user-data/functions/src/index.ts#L119) of the Cloud Function implementing the extension, **the documents are selected based on their paths** and not with a `where` query.

You could fork the code of the extension Cloud Function in order to adapt to your case and deploy your own Clown Function.

Comment: I see. The communication of what they promise to do is confusing. Thanks.